Headless automation is possible for desktop or native applications using WinAppDriver?
GUI sendkeys are not working (unable to find elements) if we lock the system, even win+R not working. Any solutions to do headless for behave framework?
Tried with PSEXEC triggering the script on the remote machine but if we lock scripts unable to find the elements
